# How to make code in Haskell to decide next character from the string is same as before character?

Tags: haskell

Now I am making code for complicated caesar cipher in Haskell.
I succeeded to make code for normal caesar cipher.
But what I want to do is rotating by key positions again after having used a letter from the string.

For example, AAA with key position 3 will be XUR.

So my problem is after move 3, how can I make next letter will be move 6, and next move 9?

Comment: I am not really following what the "same" letter here does. If I understand it correctly, you each time add `3` to the "delta", so `ABC` would encode to `XVT`, or am I missing something?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem My interpretation is that a character represented by `c :: Int` will be mapped to `(c - (n * key)) \`mod\` 26`, where `n` is the position of `c` in the string. But then the question still doesn’t make sense: as I see it, whether a letter has been used already has no relevance to this cipher.

Comment: if you add 3 to the `X`, it will be `U` to the left and again move 3 to the left which is `R`.

Comment: @bradm: yes that was more or less the same formula I had in mind.

Comment: @dagosom I interpret the result of adding 3 to `X` to be `A`; this is because counting three forward from `X` gives `Y`, `Z`, `A`.

Comment: @dasogom Also, a minor note: ‘complicated Caeser cipher’ isn’t really the best way to describe this. I would suggest calling this a modified [Trithemius cipher](https://www.dcode.fr/trithemius-cipher) instead.

Comment: @bradrn thanks for the advice! I am just a beginner of Haskell.

Comment: @dasogom: can you edit your question, and show how you solved the original Caesar cypher?

Comment: You’re welcome @dasogom! Good to see you’re learning Haskell. I still have one question though: why do you need to determine whether a character has been used before? From my knowledge of polyalphabetic substitution ciphers this should be irrelevant.

Comment: Irrespective of cryptography, if we call the string `st`, an expression testing whether character 'A' appears inside st is `elem 'A' st` and if you want to restrict the test to say the first 7 characters in st, that would be `elem 'A' (take 7 st)`  . Does that help ?

Comment: @bradrn Oh I was a stupid. I misunderstude the question. So the question wants after adding 3, adding 6, adding 9.

Comment: @dasogom That makes a lot more sense now — thanks! One standard way to do this is to use an auxilliary function (I don’t know if that’s standard terminology); that is, define `cipher myString = go myString 0`, and then define `go` as a recursive function where the last parameter is incremented for every character. Another way to do this is to do `zip [0,3..] myString` to associate each character with its shift, then `map` a shifting function over each (shift,character) pair. For doing the shift itself I recommend using `chr` and `ord` from `Data.Char`.

Comment: Or, as @WillemVanOnsem has just answered, you can use `zipWith`; I should note that this is equivalent to my previous suggestion of using `zip` and then mapping, but is a much cleaner alternative!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only need to keep track of the position if I understand it correctly. We can do so by `zipWith` the `[i, i+d ..]` list.

So we can construct a function that looks like:

```
trithemiusEncrypt :: Int -> Int -> String -> String
trithemiusEncrypt i d = zipWith _ [i, i+d .. ]
```

with `_` something we still need to fill in. This function should have type `Int -> Char -> Char`, so here `Int` is the "shift" we need to perform on the character. We can thus define this as:

```
import Data.Char(ord, chr)

trithemiusEncrypt :: Int -> Int -> String -> String
trithemiusEncrypt i d = zipWith f [i, i+d .. ]
    where f s c = chr (ca + mod (ord c - ca - s) 26)
          ca = ord 'A'
```

This gives us the expected result:

```
Prelude> trithemiusEncrypt 3 3 "AAA"
"XUR"
Prelude> trithemiusEncrypt 3 3 "ABC"
"XVT"
```

Comment: What about Input has to be: `encrypt 3 "AAA"` ?

Comment: @dasogom: that I leave as an exercise :)

Comment: `encode n ss = zipWith shift [n, n*2..n*(length(ss)] [ss] ` is not work?

Comment: @dasogom: why do you expect that definition to work in the first place? Try to think how you can write `encode n ss` in terms of `trithemiusEncrypt`.

Comment: Btw what about space? For example, `AAA AAA` have to be 'YWU SQO'. If `zipWith` count space it becom `YWU QOM`.

Comment: @dasogom: I would really advice that you look *how* the above function is working, and adapt it, instead of just to copy it.

Comment: Thx for advice and I will try to take a look first.